# Waiting for 2 AJAX request to complet (d3.js) whit optimize the temp waiting?

Tags: ajax, d3.js

I need 2 ajax request are complet before run the callback function RUN_ACTIONS() of the first request, but how waiting it ( whit optimize the temp waiting )?

```
function ajax() {
 d3.tsv( ajaxUrl,
        function(data) {
            while (!secondAJAXQueryComplet());
            RUN_ACTIONS(HEADER, data);
        }
  );
  d3.json( ajaxUrl,
        function(header) {
            define_Header(header);
        }
  );
 }
```

Comment: Or use Mike Bostock's queue: https://github.com/mbostock/queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code i run the 2 AJAX Query simultanious and wait the last answer before run my callback function RUN_ACTIONS(). but this method does not seem to me very elegant

```
function ajax() {
  var ready=false,
      datatsv=false;

  d3.tsv( ajaxUrl,
        function(data) {
            if (ready)
                RUN_ACTIONS(HEADER, data);
            else {
                ready=true;
                datatsv=data;
            }
        }
   );
   d3.json( ajaxUrl,
        function(header) {
            define_Header(header);
            if (ready)
                RUN_ACTIONS(header, datatsv);
            else {
                ready=true;
            }
        }
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't do this, you use the general callback concept:

```
function dostuff(callWhenDone) {
  // ...
  d3.tsv(ajaxUrl, function callWhenTSVCompletes(data) {
    // ...
    d3.json(ajaxUrl, function callWhenJSONCompletes(header) {
      //...
      callWhenDone(); // now we're done.
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: A little prettier/cleaner if you have time for it: https://github.com/mbostock/queue

Comment: this methode is to slow, because my php query tsv last 3 seconds and i need answer very quickly.

Comment: not knowing what TSV and JSON do, that's kind of your problem. If you don't need to wait for TSV, then fire it off and forgot about it. If you do, 3 seconds is your own doing. @AdamPearce there's a lot of cascade prettifiers, for two calls only you can probably get away with not using a waterfall or callback queue.